# How do I add trendlines to ggplot from two subsets of different lengths?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subset

I am looking to add trendlines to a scatterplot and find the intercept between the two intercepts.

The data are two subsets of a larger dataset that satisfy two separate conditions, and they are of different lengths, that is why I chose to write the code this way!

```r
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data=flightacc, aes(x=Time..s., y=acc)) + 
    geom_point(data=pushoffacc, aes(Time..s., acc))
```

which returns the following plot:
[image: Plot picture here]

Again, looking to add two separate trendlines to the distinct subsets and find their intercept. Any help greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df1 <- subset(mtcars, wt <= 3.5)
df2 <- subset(mtcars, wt > 3.5)
    
ggplot(data = df1, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = "red") +
  geom_smooth(color = "red", method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data = df2, color = "blue") +
  geom_smooth(data = df2, color = "blue", method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! This worked, just also looking for how to find the intercept of the blue and red lines. Any thooughts?